# Are global variables in a file accessible if file is included?

Tags: c, include, global-variables

I'm having strange behavior when I try to use some global variables which is included in main, in my C project.

My setup is such that I have file called `global.h` which contain variables which need to be accessed from multiple files.

Files containing specific functions which use the global variables and change them, reference those through the `extern` keyword.

My main.c include all these files (also the `global.h`). When I try to access one of the global variables from `main.c` I get some kind of strange behavior, which seems to change all global variables.

I tried to break it down to the following code. The code below seems to work as I expect, meaning that `main.c` included `a` from `global.h` and can change it.

`main.c`

```
#include "globals.h"
#include "functions.c"

int main ()
{
  printf ("a = %d\n", a);
  foo ();
  printf ("a = %d\n", a);
  a = 3;
  printf ("a = %d\n", a);
  foo ();
  printf ("a = %d\n", a);
  a = 4;
  printf ("a = %d\n", a);

  return 0;
}
```

`functions.h`

```
#ifndef GLOBALTEST_FUNCTIONS_H
#define GLOBALTEST_FUNCTIONS_H

extern a;

#endif //GLOBALTEST_FUNCTIONS_H
```

`functions.c`

```
#include "functions.h"

void foo() {
  a = 2;
}
```

`global.h`

```
#ifndef GLOBALTEST_GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALTEST_GLOBALS_H

int a = 0;

#endif //GLOBALTEST_GLOBALS_H
```

`output`

```
a = 0
a = 2
a = 3
a = 2
a = 4
```

However, this does not seems to be true in my other application.

So what I want to know:
Does the different calls change the same variable `a`? Can I access these global variables in `global.h` by including it or should I do it some other way? I want to understand if this is defined in C or if I should go bug hunting.

Comment: There's no way to know what you're doing wrong without seeing any code.  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: You should declare global variables in the .c files. In global.h use `extern -variable-` to declare that this variable is accessible among all .c files that include global.h.

Comment: I updated the question with an example code of what I mean, and what I don't  understand. @dbush

Comment: @GamalOthman can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: do NOT place variables in a header file.  Rather place the variables in a C file and the header file contain `extern` statements for those variables

Comment: @user3629249: it is `extern` *declarations*

Answer (score 0):

global variables are accessible after being included, but they need to be declared.